# How could I configure that reward amount or value for my Aura validators?

Tags: substrate-node-template, aura, poa

Now that the PoA is running with multiple Aura validators in my substrate-node-template. How could I configure that reward amount or value for my validators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working, PoA will reward the validator who created the block using the tip as the sample value for the fees, here are the steps:

1. Install the pallet_authorship

```
pallet-authorship = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.23" }
```

2. Configure the pallet to get the current author of the block

```
pub struct AuraAccountAdapter;
impl frame_support::traits::FindAuthor<AccountId> for AuraAccountAdapter {
    fn find_author<'a, I>(digests: I) -> Option<AccountId>
        where I: 'a + IntoIterator<Item=(frame_support::ConsensusEngineId, &'a [u8])>
    {
        pallet_aura::AuraAuthorId::<Runtime>::find_author(digests).and_then(|k| {
            AccountId::try_from(k.as_ref()).ok()
        })
    }
}
impl pallet_authorship::Config for Runtime {
    type FindAuthor = AuraAccountAdapter;
    type UncleGenerations = ();
    type FilterUncle = ();
    type EventHandler =  ();
}
```

3. Create OnUnbalanced implementation of Author and DealWithFees

```
use crate::{Authorship, Balances};
use frame_support::traits::{Imbalance, OnUnbalanced};
use crate::sp_api_hidden_includes_construct_runtime::hidden_include::traits::Currency;
use crate::AccountId;

type NegativeImbalance = <Balances as Currency<AccountId>>::NegativeImbalance;

pub struct Author;
impl OnUnbalanced<NegativeImbalance> for Author {
    fn on_nonzero_unbalanced(amount: NegativeImbalance) {
        if let Some(author) = Authorship::author() {
            Balances::resolve_creating(&author, amount);
        }
    }
}

pub struct DealWithFees;
impl OnUnbalanced<NegativeImbalance> for DealWithFees {
    fn on_unbalanceds<B>(mut fees_then_tips: impl Iterator<Item = NegativeImbalance>) {
        if let Some(fees) = fees_then_tips.next() {
            let mut split = fees.ration(80, 20);
            if let Some(tips) = fees_then_tips.next() {
                // for tips, if any, 80% to treasury, 20% to block author (though this can be anything)
                tips.ration_merge_into(80, 20, &mut split);
            }
            //Treasury::on_unbalanced(split.0);
            Author::on_unbalanced(split.1);
        }
    }
}
```

4. Call the implementation in the pallet_transaction_payment tuple OnChargeTransaction

```
impl pallet_transaction_payment::Config for Runtime {
    type OnChargeTransaction = CurrencyAdapter<Balances, crate::impls::DealWithFees>;
    type OperationalFeeMultiplier = ConstU8<5>;
    type WeightToFee = IdentityFee<Balance>;
    type LengthToFee = IdentityFee<Balance>;
    type FeeMultiplierUpdate = ();
}
```

Also added in my blog: https://hgminerva.wordpress.com/2022/06/21/how-to-pay-the-block-author-validator-on-a-proof-of-authority-poa-consensus-in-substrate/

Answer (score 1):

The above is about allowing the transaction fees to be split between validators. If you want inflation as well, this can currently only be done if you use `pallet-staking`. Inflationary rewards are minted in `pallet-staking`, and can configured via the `type EraPayout`. See [`EraPayout`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_staking/trait.EraPayout.html).

Comment: I am just using Aura for the time being.  I want to pay the block authors/validators of the existing PoA.

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled with OnUnbalanced on NegativeImbalance event when a fee is charged, [here is sample code](https://github.com/web3labs/ice-substrate/blob/main/runtime/arctic/src/impls.rs#L22)

You will also need to integrate authorship pallet to pass the author (validator) information, [here is a snippet for this](https://github.com/web3labs/ice-substrate/blob/main/runtime/arctic/src/lib.rs#L402).

Comment: Thanks for the response! Although FYI it is always best practice to link out and provide directly a snippet here for reference. Both for keeping people from having to jump out of the site, but more importantly because those resources may disappear latter on or change

Comment: So I need the following task for my substrate-node-template:
1. Import pallet_session
2. Import pallet_authorship
3. Implement both pallets in the /runtime/lib.rs
4. Implement OnUnbalanced event for Author struct
5. Implement OnUnbalanced event for DealtWithFees struct

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am wrong on this Mo Elshami.  These are the step on how to provide reward to your PoA validators in the substrate-node-template.

1. Import the pallet_session (runtime/Cargo.toml)

```
pallet-session = { version = "4.0.0-dev", features = [ "historical" ], path = "../../../frame/session", default-features = false }`
```

2. Import the pallet_authorship (runtime/Cargo.toml)

```
pallet-authorship = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, path = "../../../frame/authorship" }`
```

3. Implement both pallet in the /runtime/lib.rs

```
parameter_types! {
    pub const Period: u32 = 6 * HOURS;
    pub const Offset: u32 = 0;
    pub const MaxAuthorities: u32 = 100_000;
}
impl pallet_session::Config for Runtime {
    type Event = Event;
    type ValidatorId = <Self as frame_system::Config>::AccountId;
    // we don't have stash and controller, thus we don't need the convert as well.
    type ValidatorIdOf = pallet_collator_selection::IdentityCollator;
    type ShouldEndSession = pallet_session::PeriodicSessions<Period, Offset>;
    type NextSessionRotation = pallet_session::PeriodicSessions<Period, Offset>;
    type SessionManager = CollatorSelection;
    // Essentially just Aura, but lets be pedantic.
    type SessionHandler = <SessionKeys as sp_runtime::traits::OpaqueKeys>::KeyTypeIdProviders;
    type Keys = SessionKeys;
    type WeightInfo = ();
}

parameter_types! {
    pub const UncleGenerations: u32 = 0;
}
impl pallet_authorship::Config for Runtime {
    type FindAuthor = pallet_session::FindAccountFromAuthorIndex<Self, Aura>;
    type UncleGenerations = UncleGenerations;
    type FilterUncle = ();
    type EventHandler = (CollatorSelection,);
}
```

4. Implement OnUnbalanced event for Author and DealtWithFees struct

```
use crate::{Authorship, Balances, NegativeImbalance, Treasury};
use frame_support::traits::{Currency, Imbalance, OnUnbalanced};

pub struct Author;
impl OnUnbalanced<NegativeImbalance> for Author {
    fn on_nonzero_unbalanced(amount: NegativeImbalance) {
        if let Some(author) = Authorship::author() {
            Balances::resolve_creating(&author, amount);
        }
    }
}

pub struct DealWithFees;
impl OnUnbalanced<NegativeImbalance> for DealWithFees {
    fn on_unbalanceds<B>(mut fees_then_tips: impl Iterator<Item = NegativeImbalance>) {
        if let Some(fees) = fees_then_tips.next() {
            let mut split = fees.ration(80, 20);
            if let Some(tips) = fees_then_tips.next() {
                // for tips, if any, 80% to treasury, 20% to block author (though this can be anything)
                tips.ration_merge_into(80, 20, &mut split);
            }
            Treasury::on_unbalanced(split.0);
            Author::on_unbalanced(split.1);
        }
    }
}
```