How to award/transfer the transaction fee to the Validator in PoA?
parameter_types! {
    pub FeeMultiplier: Multiplier = Multiplier::one();
    pub TransactionFeePot: AccountId = AccountId::new([1u8; 32]);
}

impl pallet_transaction_payment::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type OnChargeTransaction = FungibleAdapter<Balances, ResolveTo<TransactionFeePot, Balances>>;
    type OperationalFeeMultiplier = ConstU8<5>;
    type WeightToFee = IdentityFee<Balance>;
    type LengthToFee = IdentityFee<Balance>;
    type FeeMultiplierUpdate = ConstFeeMultiplier<FeeMultiplier>;
}

Right now, I only send the fee to the TransactionFeePot. But, I'm wondering if it's possible for me to send the Fee directly to the validator. This is PoA the default config of a solochain.
I know I need this pallet_authorship
impl pallet_authorship::Config for Runtime {
    type FindAuthor = ();
    type EventHandler = ();
}

But I don't know how to set this FindAuthor. Please somebody can show me how to setup or any repo that implemented the same approach. Thank you

https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/how-could-i-configure-that-reward-amount-or-value-for-my-aura-validators/3374#3374
